# How to get error of previous iteration within optimizer.Optimizer tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement an optimizer of class optimizer.Optimizer that depends on the changes of the error at the output layer according to some error function. How would I get the error at the output layer from within the optimizer? It seems like the get_total_loss method can't be called within an optimizer. Below is the code in question and the line in apply_dense method with the #TODO is where I'm having trouble. Thanks in advance!

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import state_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.training import optimizer
import tensorflow as tf
class GradientReuse(optimizer.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate, momentum, use_locking=False, name="GradientReuse"):
        super(GradientReuse, self).__init__(use_locking, name)

        self._lr = learning_rate
        self._momentum = momentum

        # Tensor versions of the constructor arguments, created in _prepare().
        self._lr_t = None
        self._momentum_t = None

    def _prepare(self):
        self._lr_t = ops.convert_to_tensor(self._lr, name="learning_rate")
        self._momentum_t = ops.convert_to_tensor(self._momentum, name="momentum_t")

    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        # Create slots for the first and second moments.
        for v in var_list:
            self._zeros_slot(v, "m", self._name)
            self._zeros_slot(v, "loss", self._name)
            self._zeros_slot(v, "last_good_grad", self._name)

    def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        lr_t = math_ops.cast(self._lr_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
        momentum_t = math_ops.cast(self._momentum_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)

        eps = 1e-7 #cap for moving average

        m = self.get_slot(var, "m")
        last_good_grad = self.get_slot(var, "last_good_grad")
        loss = self.get_slot(var, "loss")
        cur_loss_t = tf.losses.get_total_loss() #TODO: don't know how to get current loss

        if cur_loss_t < loss:
          grad = last_good_grad
        last_good_grad_t = last_good_grad.assign(grad)

        loss_t = loss.assign(cur_loss_t)

        m_t = m.assign(lr_t * grad)#m * momentum_t + 

        var_update = state_ops.assign_sub(var, m_t)

        return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_update, m_t, cur_loss_t, loss_t, last_good_grad_t])

    def _apply_sparse(self, grad, var):
        raise NotImplementedError("Sparse gradient updates are not supported.")
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can't you pass the loss tensor to the ```__init__``` of GradientReuse? Example usage will be ```opt = GradientReuse(my_loss, learning_rate, ...).minimize(my_loss)```.